# Encode response of HTTP , it's MIME but dont' show final part of its

Tags: objective-c, ios, parsing, nsdata, mime

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
  if (_receivedData)
{
    NSString* _str = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:_receivedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
    NSLog(@"urlData........%@",_str);

    [_receivedData release], _receivedData = nil;
}

[_connection release], _connection = nil;

CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent());
}
```

When NSLOG _str don't decode the final part of MIME message (print ???), I think is a problem of encode:NSASCIIStringEncoding.

How I set encode ???

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSUTF8StringEncoding instead of NSASCIIStringEncoding.